# Testing with nightwatch in docker container

Tags: docker, vue.js, nightwatch.js

Vue app, Nightwatch tests are running locally with docker rights, how should I point my file in local file system? As:

```js
.setValue( 
'input#front', 
require('path').resolve(...), 
function (result) { this.assert.equal(result.status, 0) })
```

where `...` - location of my file, as: `/home/user/projects/myproject/src/assets/temp.jpg`

also, will setValue catch this listener?:

```js
document.getElementById('front').addEventListener('change', this.readFront)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a local file on container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876778/how-can-i-use-a-local-file-on-container)

Comment: It was my first idea, so I've checked that my container contains needed files with "test -e /src/src/assets/temp.jpg && echo file exists" and it exists, but setValue result returns -1 with: "File not found: /src/src/assets/temp.jpg"