# Can apps in Docker take input/output from python on base OS?

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, containers

If I get a linux server and run a .Net Core app over docker, can this app interact with python scripts running on the base linux OS?

I'd like to pass strings to python's nltk to make a python list of part of speech tags, and pass this list back to the .Net Core app which would be running in docker.

...Or would i be able to run the .Net core app and python scripts within the same container?

Uninmportant extra details:
The reason I ask is because I'd rather not use options like IronPython or any NuGet package working with Java or Python to do NLP (natural language processing). I already work with NLTK in python, but my situation calls for a .Net app, and I'm assuming it might be easier and cheaper to run a linux vps with docker than windows on shared hosting.

Comment: what is the output of the ntlk python script, text ?

Comment: Yes, the output would be text.

Comment: I couldnt find this info before because I'm new to containers and found many unuseful results from the search terms I tried, but this answer here seems to shed light on a way this could be done. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40053238/9977241

Comment: how about storeing the output from the python script on a file that can be access from the .NET core app ?

Comment: Sounds fine with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any writable resourse that is accesible from both the Linux and the Docker instance

For instance you could store the output from the python script on a file that can be access from the .NET core app.

And from the example above you can try any shared resource that might work better for your scenario

Maybe this answer can help you - [How can I use a local file on container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876778/how-can-i-use-a-local-file-on-container)