# error: The spec file is not found, Check the path of the OpenAPI spec and try again

Tags: docker, openapi-generator-cli

I have a problem with generating client API using [openapi generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) on Docker.
After runing:

```
docker run --rm -v "${PWD}:/local" openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i ./petstore.yml -g typescript-angular -o api/petstore
```

I got an:

```
[error] The spec file is not found: ./petstore.yml
[error] Check the path of the OpenAPI spec and try again.
```

Also tried:

```
docker run --rm -v "${PWD}" openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i ./petstore.yml -g typescript-angular -o api/petstore

docker run --rm -v "${PWD}:/local" openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i petstore.yml -g typescript-angular -o api/petstore
```

Comment: I just published a tutorial (video) to show how to use openapi generator cli via Docker on Windows (command prompt): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MuEP01h1XU. If you follow the steps, it should work for you.

Answer (score 9):

Fix:

```
docker run --rm -v "${PWD}:/local" openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i /local/petstore.yml -g typescript-angular -o /local/api/petstore
```

My problem was in not understanding how `-v "${PWD}:/local"` works.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876778/how-can-i-use-a-local-file-on-container) helped me.

When we run:

```
docker run --rm -v "${PWD}:/local" openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i /local/petstore.yml -g typescript-angular -o /local/api/petstore
```

Docker runs container on `openapitools/openapi-generator-cli` image. Inside this container, we don't have access to local files. To fix this we need to use `-v [localDir]:[containerDir]`. Now you can use the contents of `localDir` inside the container by using `containerDir` folder.

I hope this makes sense.